# Sort list of objects by multiple properties and using natural sorting

Tags: sorting, kotlin

I would like to sort a list of objects by a Boolean property and then a String property.

The String should be compared case-insensitively, and using natural sort order as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order)

An example could be sorting persons by alive and then name:

```
class Person(
public val name: String,
public val alive : Boolean
```

)

I want the name sorting to look like this:

- "1 Adam"
- "13 Adam"
- "20 adam"
- "100 Adam"
- "Adam 0"
- "Adam 1"
- "adam 10"
- "Adam 20"
- "Adam 100"
- "Brian"
- "George"

I have experimented with sorting a list of strings using the naturalOrder Comparable, and it does look promising although it seems to be case sensitive:

```
  val personsStr = setOf("1 Adam", "21 Adam", "13 Adam", "Adam 1", "adam 1", "Adam 0", "Adam 20", "Adam 11", "Bryan", "George")
    val personStrSorted = personsStr.sortedWith(naturalOrder())
```

What I am looking for is something like:

```
persons.sortedWith( compareBy<Person>{ it.alive }.thenBy{ it.name.toLowerCase() /*and done using natural sorting*/ } )
```

Question:
In which way(s) can the desired sorting be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat hacky solution: Split your set into 2 sets by `alive` and sort both sets by `name` (this results in a natural order)::

```
val personsStr = setOf( Person("1 Adam", true ), Person("21 Adam", false), Person("13 Adam", true), Person( "Bryan", true) )   
val personsAlive = personsStr.filter{it.alive}.sortedBy{it.name}
val personsNotAlive = personsStr.filter{!it.alive}.sortedBy{it.name}
```

then you can merge them:

```
val result = setOf(personsAlive, personsNotAlive)
```

Comment: Instead of using `filter` twice with opposite predicates, you should prefer using [`partition`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html) which gives the 2 lists in one go. That aside, I don't believe this answers the question, because what the OP is looking for seems to be a different natural ordering (not the alphabetical one that will be used by `sortedBy(() -> String)`).

Comment: Thanks for your hint to ´´´partition´´´! There are 2 different sorting order for String, alphabetically and natural. My answer sorts natural, since this was asked in the question (I checked that)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to implement your notion of "natural ordering" manually.

The "natural order" in Kotlin is simply defined as the order by which `Comparable<T>` implementations are sorted when no special comparator is provided ([doc link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-ordering.html)):

> First, there is natural order. It is defined for inheritors of the Comparable interface. Natural order is used for sorting them when no other order is specified.

Using `naturalOrder()` should give you the usual order defined by the `compareTo` operator for any implementor of `Comparable`. This means that for string, the natural order is in fact the *alphabetical* order.

If you know that your names are always in the form `<name>`, `<num> <name>` or `<name> <num>`, you should be able to implement a comparator by actually parsing the number.

One way to do it could be something like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val personsStr = setOf("1 Adam", "21 Adam", "100 Adam", "Adam 1", "adam 1", 
                           "Adam 3", "Adam 20", "Adam 11", "Bryan", "George", "bob" )
    val persons = personsStr.map { Person(name = it, alive = kotlin.random.Random.nextBoolean()) }
    
    val personsSorted = persons.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.alive }, { it.name.parseName() }))
    
    println(personsSorted.joinToString("\n"))
}

data class Person(
    val name: String,
    val alive: Boolean
)

data class ComplexName(
    val leadingNum: Int?,
    val shortName: String,
    val trailingNum: Int?
) : Comparable<ComplexName> {

    override operator fun compareTo(other: ComplexName) = compareValuesBy(this, other, comparator, { it })
    
    companion object {
        private val comparator = compareBy<ComplexName>(
            { it.leadingNum ?: Int.MAX_VALUE }, // no leading number is behind those with leading number
            { it.shortName.toLowerCase() },
            { it.trailingNum },
        )
    }
}

fun String.parseName(): ComplexName {
    val parts = split(" ")
    return when (parts.size) {
        1 -> ComplexName(null, this, null)
        2 -> {
            val (first, second) = parts
            val firstNum = first.toIntOrNull()
            when (firstNum) {
                null -> ComplexName(null, first, second.toInt())
                else -> ComplexName(firstNum, second, null)
            }
        }
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("unsupported name format: $this")
    }
}
```

You can run this there: https://pl.kotl.in/u9O2wBFgk

Alternatively, you could define `Person` with a `ComplexName` property in the first place to avoid computing it each time when comparing.

Note that you can technically implement a comparator with natural ordering with fancier parsing, generalizing the approach for numbers in any position. It would be trickier to deal with numbers inside words though, but that depends on your goal.